# Why does MySql return **Long**, how to get **Float**

Tags: java, mysql

i have query

```
select sum(rating)/count(*) from Rating r where r.studyCourseId=:id
```

when i try do this:

```
return em.createNamedQuery("getAverageRating", Float.class)
                .setParameter("id", studyCourseId)
                .getSingleResult();
```

> Type specified for TypedQuery [Float] is incompatible with query
> return type [class java.lang.Long]

why does MySql return **Long**, how to get **Float**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to force float/double precision is to ensure that either the numerator or denominator be float/double:

```sql
select 1.0*sum(rating) / count(*) from Rating r where r.studyCourseId = :id
```

By multiplying the numerator by `1.0`, we can force it to be float/double.